# Is it possible to add Fair scheduler pools programmatically in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm developing an application where several users use the same SparkContext to launch their queries to a Spark Cluster.

As the Spark documentation states (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/job-scheduling.html#fair-scheduler-pools), with the Fair scheduler, you can assign a different pool for every user and they'll get a fair share of the cluster resources but every pool will be set up with the default pool configuration (scheduling mode FIFO, weight 1, and minShare 0).

Given that we don't know in advance which users can connect to the application, we can't set up a configuration file for the fair scheduler pools for all the users.

So, in order to give a pool to every user dynamically and set up every pool with a FAIR scheduling mode, I think there might be 2 options:

1. Change the default pool behaviour in order to change the scheduling mode to FAIR. Is it possible? How?
2. Generate a scheduler pool dynamically and programmatically in order to add a scheduler pool when a user connects to the application for first time and that pool should be created with a FAIR scheduling mode. Is it possible? How?

Thanks in advance